# Transfer Data from ListView Activity

Tags: android, listview, listactivity, onitemclicklistener

i wanna transfer clicked item data from `MainActivity` to some `DetailActivity`, here is the code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,TourDetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("tourId", tours.get(position).getId());     
    startActivity(intent);
    }
```

here is the adapter:

```
public class TourListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tour> {

Context context;
List<Tour> tours;

public TourListAdapter(Context context, List<Tour> tours) {
    super(context, android.R.id.content, tours);
    this.context = context;
    this.tours = tours;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_tour, null);

    Tour tour = tours.get(position);

    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
    tv.setText(tour.getTitle());

    tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.priceText);
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    tv.setText(nf.format(tour.getPrice()));

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    int res = context.getResources().getIdentifier(
            tour.getImage(), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    if (res != 0 ) {
        iv.setImageResource(res);
    }
    return view;
}

}
```

i know that the problem is `tours.get(position).getId()`. but i don't know how to fix it.
Thanks

Comment: What's tours?! can you post more code?

Comment: put your `adapter class`. Are you using  `Custom Adapter`?

Comment: Code is not clear please put clear code. What is Tours?

Comment: put your full code, if there is error post that also

Comment: @SaNtoRiaN @sur007 tours is a `List<Tour>`

Comment: @milad.moafi ok and what's the Tour and what's the adapter? please more code or no one can help!

Comment: @SaNtoRiaN ok, i'll handle

Comment: @milad.moafi Till now I don't see errors, the error is in `tours` maybe you filled it wrong, add the part where you add items to it also what does the logcat say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass the object data between two activity via intent.you should use parcelable or Serializable.I did this sample using Serializable.
Please try this one.

Tour Custom object class will be.

```
public class Tour implements Serializable{
String title;
String price;
int Image;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public int getImage() {
    return Image;
}

public void setImage(int image) {
    Image = image;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}
```

}

and your array adapter will be

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tour> {

Context context;
List<Tour> tours;

public Adapter(Context context, List<Tour> tours) {
    super(context,R.layout.list_item_tour, tours);
    this.context = context;
    this.tours = tours;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_tour, null);

    Tour tour = tours.get(position);

    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
    tv.setText(tour.getTitle());

    tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.priceText);
   /* NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    tv.setText(nf.format(tour.getPrice()));
   */
     ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
       /*int res = context.getResources().getIdentifier(
            tour.getImage(), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    if (res != 0 ) {
        iv.setImageResource(res);
      }*/
      return view;
      }

     }
```

And in your first activity i.e in MainActivity paste this code.

```
   Adapter adapter=new Adapter(this,tours);
    listvView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listvView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Tour tour=(Tour)listvView.getAdapter().getItem(i);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Demo.this,Demo2.class);
            intent.putExtra("tourId",tour);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

and in your Second Activity(i.e DetailActivity) oncreate paste this code

```
   Tour objects=(Tour)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("tourId");
    Log.e("Selected Tour title is ",objects.getTitle());
```